# UIPasteBoard Keyboard Extensions - setting the .image attribute in the global pasteboard does not remove previous image and increases Heap usage

Tags: ios, keyboard, uipasteboard

// imageToPaste is a copy of an image in a UICollectionView

UIPasteboard *pasteboard;

pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];

[pasteboard setImage:imageToPaste];

In my keyboard extension I have many images that can be selected and consequently pasted to the generalPasteboard.  The code above works and the image is placed onto the general paste board, however the heap memory increases with every image I select from the CollectionView.

I make a copy of the image from the CollectionView and assign it to the pasteboard via the setter.  However, watching my heap memory increase is not the expected behavior.  Can someone please explain why the pasteboard would not release the previous UIImage when the setter is called.  Is there a way to assure that the previous UIImage that was set is not retained?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: After looking over this problem, I think the real solution is trying to get the system to free up any memory used by the clipboard.  @autoreleasepool block around the the pasteboard code, seems to force the system to release the memory occupied by zero ref count objects.  Hope this helps someone.